# Can't display the content in the iPhone simulator, it crashes, but i get no errors

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to display my code in the iPhone simulator, but actually it does not work and have no idea what did i wrong. I think i made some basic, beginner mistakes, but it's very frustrating. I don't get any errors, but after i run the app it crashes and i get these lines in the log section: (I'm using a storyboard and the newest Xcode version and Cocoapods)

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MainViewController 0x109f330c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key overlays.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102005495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101d6499e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102089919 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000101945530 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102001400 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100b6c8a6 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1131
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100a06b0c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 245
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100a07149 -[UIViewController loadView] + 112
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100a073b7 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100a07777 -[UIViewController view] + 29
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010094796b -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100947c70 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000100950ffa -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010090cc98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1788
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000100910a0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000100921d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000100922216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000100912086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010338a71a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010338a1e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f87679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f8744e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fb0903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fafd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001009102e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000100911e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    26  GPUCoco                             0x0000000100001ed3 main + 115
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001040465fd start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

This is my MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TablViewCell.h"
#import <GPUImage.h>
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *filterNames;
}

//- (void) overlayFilter1;
//- (void) coolingLookup;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *filtersTable;

- (IBAction)filters:(id)sender;

//- (IBAction)overlays:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender;

@end
```

The MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

    @interface MainViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MainViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        filterNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         [self coolingLookup];
    }


    //get number of sections in tableView from challenges array
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    //get number of rows by counting number of challenges
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return filterNames.count;
    }


    //setup cells in tableView
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //setup cell
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TablViewCell";
        TablViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [filterNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.imageFilename.text = [filteredDictionary objectForKey:@"imagefilename"];
        cell.filteredImage.image = [filteredDictionary objectForKey:@"filteredImage"];

        return cell;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [filterNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        _imageView.image = [filteredDictionary objectForKey:@"filteredImage"];
    }

    /*
     #pragma mark - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
     // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */



    /*
     **********************************************************************************************
     FILTERS
     **********************************************************************************************
     */
    - (void) coolingLookup {
        UIImage *filteredimage;
        NSString *filename = @"lookup_cooling.png";

        GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imageView.image];

        GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
        GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
        [stillImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];
        [lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];

        [stillImageSource processImage];
        [lookupImageSource processImage];
        [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer]; // megvaltozott a class neve
        filteredimage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

        NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:filteredimage, @"filteredImage", filename, @"filename", nil];

        [filterNames insertObject:filteredDictionary atIndex:0];

        [_filtersTable reloadData];
    }

    //    /*
    //     **********************************************************************************************
    //     OVERLAYS
    //     **********************************************************************************************
    //     */
    //    - (void) overlayFilter1 {
    //        NSString *filename = @"fujiFrame.png";
    //        
    //        GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter *overlayBlendFilter = [[GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter alloc] init];
    //        GPUImagePicture *pic1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imageView.image];
    //        GPUImagePicture *pic2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
    //        
    //        [pic1 addTarget:overlayBlendFilter];
    //        [pic1 processImage];
    //        [pic2 addTarget:overlayBlendFilter];
    //        [pic2 processImage];
    //        
    //       UIImage *blendedImage = [overlayBlendFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation::_imageView.image.imageOrientation];
    //        
    //        NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:blendedImage, @"filteredImage", filename, @"filename", nil];
    //        
    //        [filterNames insertObject:filteredDictionary atIndex:0];
    //        
    //        [_filtersTable reloadData];
    //    }

            - (IBAction)undo:(id)sender {
                _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo01.png"];
                [filterNames removeAllObjects];
                [self coolingLookup];
            }

    //        - (IBAction)overlays:(id)sender {
    //            [filterNames removeAllObjects];
    //            [self overlayFilter1];
    //        }

            - (IBAction)filters:(id)sender {
                [filterNames removeAllObjects];
                [self coolingLookup];
            }
            - (void) applyFilter:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

                if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                    [self coolingLookup];
                }
            }
    @end
```

TablViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TablViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *filteredImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *imageFilename;
@end
```

TablViewCell.m

```
#import "TablViewCell.h"

@implementation TablViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: More than likely, your storyboard hooks up views to outlets that don't exist anymore.

Comment: I commented out one button and it's method, i think everything else must exist.

Comment: The outlet that causes the crash is called `overlays`. I bet you used to have a property named `overlays` before, and removed it without removing the connection in your storyboard.

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint set?  If not got to debug panel and click the plus then add exception breakpoint. Most of the time it helps.

Comment: Yes, i did it. Now i removed the button from the storyboard, and  it's property from the TablViewCell.h, but it crashed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual error you get when you copy paste or edit classes that are connected to `IBOutlet`s. Most likely a connection between an outlet and code is broken, meaning that **you have created an outlet on storyboard** and then deleted the property in code manually.

The exception actually does tell you what is wrong. Connection in storyboard is looking for `overlay` property in your chosen view controller, but since it does not exist, it crashes.

So take a look at the view controller on storyboard and try to **Control+Click** all elements on it and find the overlay connection. Remove it and the code should run.

*Also check for the class you chose for the view controller and all the views on it. You can find this in Interface Builder. This could also be the cause of the crash.*

Comment: There was an unexisting property from the text field. I've deleted it, but crashed again and drop me back to the GPUImagePicture.m. And get this in the log section: 2014-04-23 16:50:33.551 GPUCoco[1758:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[GPUImagePicture initWithCGImage:smoothlyScaleOutput:], /Users/szabolcsvarga/Documents/GPU/GPUCoco/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Source/iOS/GPUImagePicture.m:72
(lldb)

Comment: If you check what the assertion is in the file you posted, (`GPUImagePicture.m`) it gives you this:

`NSAssert( widthOfImage > 0 && heightOfImage > 0, @"Passed image must not be empty - it should be at least 1px tall and wide");`

So obviously the image you send to this method is either of 0px width or 0px height (or both). Check the `CGImage` if it is created correctly. I cannot pinpoint the exact problem without the code.

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode, when you're looking at storyboard go to utilities bar (the right one), find there Connections inspector and check for broken connections. It's really the most likely to be a problem.

Comment: I don't see broken connections there. How should it look like? Is it marked with red?

Comment: Search for 'overlays' among referencing outlets. You don't have any IBOutlet named 'overlays', but looks like Xcode doesn't think so. Find which view was connected to 'overlays' and remove this connection.

Comment: I've removed it a little bit earlier. I've deleted the button in the storyboard and the property from the class where it was connected. Now there's nothing named 'overlay' in the connections inspector and elsewhere in the header files, but still crashing.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, in this line:

```
NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [filterNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

NSDictionary does not have objects at a specific index, but instead it has objects for key value pairs.
Either change filteredDictionary to be an NSArray, or change the way you look for values in filteredDictionary to be

```
[filteredDictionary objectForKey:somekey];
```